# How to Stich multiple java.awt.Image objects

Tags: java, swing

Refereing to my previous question,

[How to Stich to Image objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682364/how-to-stich-to-image-objects-in-java)

I successfully stiched two java.awt.Image objects, now I need to stich multiple objects of the same type. Is there any API or library available for that

Comment: Are you related to any of the other dozen or so users here named Imran? http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fusers+imran

Answer (score 0):

You want to stitch multiple images together into one larger image? Sum up all the width / heights of the tiles, create a new `BufferedIage`, get the graphics object from it, and do `g.drawImage(tile1, xOffset, yOffset)`, `g.drawImage(tile2, xOffset2, yOffset2)`, and so on.